# How to process recurring payments in Square Connect API

Tags: square-connect

Is this possible without having to send a Square invoice? According to the [recurring payments feature FAQ](https://squareup.com/townsquare/how-to-recurring-payments#im-a-developer-and-i-want-to-bill-my-customers-automatically-in-app---can-i-integrate-squares-recurring-billing-feature-via-api), processing recurring payments is not possible yet. I'm not sure this is out of date as there is API documentation for [processing recurring payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/processing-recurring-payments-ruby).

If it is possible, is there a way to define that an order is recurring and what the dates/frequency in the Checkout API? Or is it expected to call the charge API with the card on file each subscription billing period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter, call the API whenever you want to make a charge. Thanks for the heads up about the old FAQ! Also check out the blog post on using PHP for recurring charges: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/recurring-charges-with-php-and-card-on-file-60f2bcb9aeac